# Multiple content databases and Multiple search agents

Tags: content-database, database, optimization

So I have one big database which is over 1 TB now, and also this is my content database which is connected to SharePoint 2010. Although full and incremental crawl go well and search works(also i am not sure that this even makes it faster). But, search is very slow. Several tests show about 15 20 seconds time used for one search. So  I want to optimise it, and want to check this idea:

I want to divide this db into several smaller, which will be divided by years. And create search agents, which will search the query parallely in all database(analogy: you have one big library and one librarian or you have three libraries which is three parts of previous big library and you have 3 librarians). [is it even possible?] Will it work out? or should I look for something different ? Or can I make several search agents in one database?

P.S. I am not a super rockstar in SharePoint, so please do not criticize too hard.